# CSS styling to display word properly in span

Tags: css

I have used below template to generate HTML, Now the problem is when I resize the window then text in the span not showing correctly, In given screenshot "aborted" word is broken down in two lines which not what I expected. How do I fix this issue?

```
   template: _.template([
      '<div class="notes">',
      '<label class="control-label"><%=label%>:</label>',
      '<span><%=text%></span></div>'
    ].join("\n"))
```

CSS:

```
.notes {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  font-family: Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

div.notes label.control-label {
  min-width: 0px;
}
```

Below is Screenshot from my HTML page.

[image: This is span and word is breaking when I resize the window]

Comment: Thanks for including more info. Remove `word-break: break-all;` and
`word-wrap: break-word;` to stop the word from breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have `white-space` set to `pre-wrap`. You need to check if the whole code is injected inside `<pre>` or you need to reset the `white-space` property by:

```
span {white-space: normal;}
```

Comment: I already tried that before posting the question but no luck.

Comment: @n33rma You need to provide more information to check buddy. Can we see the working code somewhere?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I think you need more information before this question can be answered, a reproducible example in the question is a requirement.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Yes, but this is not a guess, this could be the reason. Only issue is that, the working solution is ambiguous here.

Comment: But it is a guess because it didn't fix the problem which resulted in you needing more information as you've just asked for an example yourself ! I suggest voting to close the question until a reproducible example has been provided.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Voted to close. Waiting for the OP to get a reproducible snippet so that I will update the answer as well.

Comment: I have included the CSS in question, Please take a look.

Comment: @n33rma Remove this line please: `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: That fixed my issue.